# How can I create a nutrition Front of Label image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels

[image]

I am looking to create a Latex image of the label below which is becoming standard on UK food packets. What would the TikZ code look like for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. This isn't really such a difficult task. What have you tried and what are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you are waiting for a TikZ-maven to bite, here is my effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  Follow the link for more information about Metapost. You need to compile this example with `lualatex`.

The missing "Energy" tab is left as an exercise for the reader.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    vardef finger(expr agent, weight, type, rda) = 
        save P; picture P;
        save S, C; path S, C;
        save H; color H; 
        H = if type = "LOW" : 1/256(140, 195, 108)
        elseif type = "MED" : 1/256(239, 179,  76)
        elseif type = "HIGH": 1/256(223,  99,  58)
        else: white fi; 
        save r; numeric r; r = 3/4;
        C = fullcircle scaled 72;
        S = subpath (2-r, 2+r) of C -- subpath (6-r, 6+r) of C -- cycle;
        P = image(
            fill S withcolor H;
            draw S;
            label(if abs(agent) > 6: "\small" & fi agent, 24 up);
            label("\Large\textbf{" & weight & "}", 10 up);
            fill superellipse(16 left, 6 up, 16 right, 6 down, .85) shifted 6 down withcolor white;
            label(type, 6 down);
            label("\large" & rda, 24 down);
            draw (left--right) scaled 40 shifted 16 down 
                cutbefore subpath (2, 3) of S
                cutafter  subpath (5, 6) of S;
        );
        P
    enddef;
    label("Each serving (150g) contains", 44 up);
    draw finger("Fat", "3.0g", "LOW", "4\%") shifted 40 left;
    draw finger("Saturates", "1.3g", "LOW", "7\%");
    draw finger("Sugar", "34g", "HIGH", "38\%") shifted 40 right;
    draw finger("Salt", "0.9g", "MED", "15\%") shifted 80 right;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent your code. The figure is the same of the picture of the OP. +1